# What is the most optimal way of solving this problem?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, segment-tree, fenwick-tree

I saw this coding question on an online coding competition but I couldn't find the most optimal solution.
Here is the question:
"You are given an array A of N integers and Q queries.Each query is of the following type :
1 pos val: Update the element at index pos to val
2 pos : Find the smallest index i less than or equal to pos such that all elements between i and pos are same."

I somehow believe that we can use segment tree but I could not figure out what each index of the segment tree will represent.

Comment: Is there some other kind of optimal than "most"?

Answer (score 0):

Here`s O(N +  Q log^2 N) approach:

1. Build a segment tree for given array
2. In each segment tree node store minimum number of interval and maximum number in interval
3. Now queries of type 1 can be done by simple update on segmenent tree
4. For queries of type 2 we can use binary search to find smallest i such that minimum value in range[i, pos] is equal to maximum value in same range